# Proving $\tilde H_0(X) \approx H_0(X,x_0)$ question

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

> Prove $\tilde H_0(X) \approx H_0(X,x_0)$

The proof in the book shows that:

$H_0(X) \approx \tilde H_0(X) \oplus \Bbb Z$

and therefore since $H_0(X)$ is free abelian, the result follows from this corollary:

> If $X$ is a space with basepoint $x_0$ then $H_0(X, x_0)$ is a free abelian group of (possibly infinite) rank $r$, where $X$ has exactly $r+1$ path components.

I can't see how $\tilde H_0(X) \approx H_0(X,x_0)$ follows from this.

Can someone explain how it does?

Comment: Isn't it simply that $\widetilde H_0(X) \cong \mathbb Z^{\oplus r} \cong H_0(X, x_0)$?

Comment: I accidentally added a tilde over $H_0(X, x_0)$ in the problem and corrected it.  And how did you get $\tilde H_0(X) \approx \Bbb Z ^ {\oplus r}$?

Comment: Because $H_0(X) \cong \mathbb Z^{\oplus (r+1)}$. Two points in $X$ are equivalent in homology iff they lie in the same path component, so $H_0(X)$ is a free abelian group whose rank is equal to the number of path components, which here is $r + 1$.

Comment: So since $X$ has $r+1$ path components with rank $H_0(X) = r+1$ and rank $H_0(X,x_0) = r$ then $H_0(X) \approx \bar H_0(X) \oplus \Bbb Z$.  Or $\Bbb Z^{r+1} \approx \tilde H_0(X) \oplus \Bbb Z$ implies $\tilde H_0(X) \approx \Bbb Z^r$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kenny Wong said in the comments, it is because both are free Abelian of rank $r$, where $r+1$ is the number of path components of $X$. The corollary you state says that this is the case for $H_0(X,x_0)$. On the other hand, a basic fact of the theory is that $H_0(X)$ is free Abelian with rank $r+1$ (see e.g. [here](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Zeroth_homology_is_free_on_set_of_path_components)). Therefore, since $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus (r+1)} \cong H_0(X) \cong \tilde H_0(X) \oplus \Bbb Z$, and because direct summands of free Abelian groups are themselves free Abelian, it follows that the summand $\tilde H_0(X)$ is free Abelian of rank $r$.